# Set a default value for fork in javac ant

Tags: ant, task, javac

I have a requirement of using fork=true through out my build. i am looking at setting it globally and use it across my build machine. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Ant's `<presetdef>` declares new tasks based on existing tasks.

The following fragment defines a `<javac>` task with the `fork` attribute set:

```
<presetdef name="my-javac">
   <javac fork="yes"/>
</presetdef>
```

`<my-javac>` can be called with any of `<javac>`'s attributes:

```
<my-javac srcdir="${my.src}" deprecation="no"/>
```

A word of warning: Specifying the `fork` attribute in a call to `<my-javac>` will override the `fork` attribute specified in the `<presetdef>`:

```
<!-- Overrides my-javac's default fork attribute -->
<my-javac srcdir="${my.src}" deprecation="no" fork="no"/>
```

`<presetdef>` is only useful for setting defaults, not for enforcing requirements.

- [PreSetDef documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/presetdef.html)

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no such kind of global switch.

If you have many `javac` in your build file, consider:

Solution 1:

```
<property name="fork" value="yes" />
```

and then, in any place that you call `javac`,

```
<javac ... fork="${fork}" ....>
```

Solution 2:

The automatically generated ant build file of Netbeans project uses this: wrap `javac` using a `macrodef`, and then use this `macrodef` in the build file.

You can check any Netbeans project, for `build-impl.xml` in the `nbproject` folder.